Square wave detector for safety circuit
I am trying to make a circuit that is similar to a watchdog circuit so if a processor locks up the line will go low if the incoming line is 'stuck' high or low. I started with a rectifier that is going into a schmitt trigger and then changed it around so it could handle the high and low case (stuck off and stuck on for more than ~20msec). Right now I'm going for a 1-2ms square wave detection.
My biggest issue is now I need to realize the circuit and need a higher voltage for the schmitt trigger threshold voltage to get the circuit more robust and noise tolerant.
My question is, can I improve the rectified voltage of the circuit before the schmitt trigger? Has anyone built a similar circuit and can offer improvements?



Why the AC coupling?

@ChrisKnudsen - That's so it will indicate failure if the input line is stuck high or low.

A more conventional approach is to use an edge-triggered monostable. If the line is stuck high or low, there will be no edges, so the monostable will time out, and reset the processor.

@jayben I tried a few of those and couldn't get the results I wanted, in the circuits that do use one, it's essentially functioning like a comparator and it really the rectifier that is doing all the work, so I ditched the monostable vibrator because I don't need edge detection or a delay window.

Perhaps something like this. You can use a Schmitt trigger inverter.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab


I like that design

Here are the other ways do this with a voltage doubler:

I couldn't get the voltage tripler to work and I don't have additional time to tweak it, but the voltage doubler gets you into the 0.5V range which is in the range of some schmitt triggers thus avoiding comparators and additional cost.

